# Facebook Like Box: changing the width by jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I have this site im building and I decided I want to put a facebook like box on it in the sidebar. The site has 2 resolutions depending on window width. Dependant on which css is loaded the sidebar will change size.

In the large css I want the facebook like box 410px wide and in the small css I want the facebook like box 200px wide.

Now im not that amazing with jquery so if anyone could help me out in how to do this I would be really greatful. An example of what I'm looking to do can be seen on http://net.tutsplus.com

I have it like this so far:

```
    <div class="block facebookLikeBox">

    </div>

    $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        $('.facebookLikeBox').html('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheFinishedBox/191240420888444" width="410" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>');  
        }
    }
    else {
        $('.facebookLikeBox').html('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheFinishedBox/191240420888444" width="200" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>'); 
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

And i have this in the head

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Not quite sure what to do here as it's not loading anything.

EDIT:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width > 1024) {
        $('#sidebar .tip').addClass('vertical');
        $('.facebookLikeBox').html('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheFinishedBox/191240420888444" width="410" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>');
        FB.FBXML.parse(document.getElementsByClassName('.facebookLikeBox')); 
   } else {
       $('#sidebar .tip').removeClass('vertical');
       $('.facebookLikeBox').html('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheFinishedBox/191240420888444" width="200" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>');
        FB.FBXML.parse(document.getElementsByClassName('.facebookLikeBox')); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});



<head><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script></head>
```

Here's an update, if you're curious: here it is live: http://thefinishedbox.com

Comment: do you have the connection to your FB-App? There is no sign of that js-code... It also needs the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` object...

Comment: @Maximilian Ehlers It works fine if I just paste it in the sidebar, I do have it connected. Problem is I need it to pretty much reload itself dependant on the browser size :|

Answer (score 2):

I have bit similar problem..But you can solve it lighter:) Have you tried to call this on end of your script?

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementsByClassName('.facebookLikeBox'));
```

It might help..

Of course you must have the javascript SDK loaded..:)

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
there is detailed description what it does..There is some code which you have to add to your site..
but you have it loaded already..I think so..It does the script in your head..But I am not 100% sure:)
What the FB.FBXML function?Did it worked?You can try it too if you are using chrome when you click on inspect element and then on esc key..there is console where you can run some javascript..The same about firebug in firefox

Comment: Still not changing the size upon browser width :/

Comment: @Sima I updated the post, Also with a link to the live version. It's not dissapearing no :/

Comment: oh:)sorry it has to be FB.XFBML.parse()..you must not specify the element..it will parse whole code. for develop does not matter

Comment: and what do you say about this?
(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.canvas.setautoresize/)
I am seeking on the developers page fot my problem solution and I found it..and there is too the setSize one…)

Comment: Ha, you had it all along, but you just got the letters in the wrong order! It's FB.XFBML.parse(); I'll give you the green tick, thanks for your help :) I guess I had it in the wrong order all along aswell haha.

Comment: Do me a favour and edit your post to FB.XFBML.parse(); just incase anyone see's this in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width > 1200) {
        $('#sidebar .tip').addClass('vertical');
        if (!$.browser.msie) {
            $('.facebookLikeBox').html('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheFinishedBox/191240420888444" width="410" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>');
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
  } else {
        $('#sidebar .tip').removeClass('vertical');
        if (!$.browser.msie) {
            $('.facebookLikeBox').html('<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/TheFinishedBox/191240420888444" width="200" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>');
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    }

}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```